# Why are 6/5 chords written in different ways?

Tags: notation, chords, engraving

Sometimes the 6th of a 6/5 chord is displaced to the right and other times the 5th is displaced to the left. Why?

[image: 6/5 chord with 5th displaced to the left]

[image: 6/5 chord with 6th displaced to the right]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Imagine that these chords had shorter note values, such that they had stems.

The stem for the first example would go downwards:

[image: 6/5 chord with 5th displaced to the left, downward stem added]

And the stem for the second example would go upwards:

[image: 6/5 chord with 6th displaced to the right, upward stem added]

In both cases, for the pair of notes that make up the interval of a second: the lower note goes on the left side of the stem, and the upper note  goes on the right.  The rest of the notes go on the same side of the stem that they normally would.

---

#### Reference as requested in comment

As Elaine Gould puts it in *Behind Bars*, p. 48:

> To write intervals a second apart, place the lower note on the left-hand side of the stem, the upper note on the right-hand side.

---

It seems a bit arbitrary when there aren't any stems, but whether or not there are stems shouldn't affect the correct alignment.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?  From the examples given, the rule could just as well be "the note head on the line is the one that gets displaced."

Answer (score 0):

Where there's likely to be a squash, as in the top two notes in each case here, the lower note goes on the left, the higher on the right. This is the case for all chords, not just 6/5s. Simple!

Comment: That doesn't explain the vertical alignment with the rest of the notes in the chord.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace - actually, with that rule, it would make more sense for the first example to have the D F and A aligned, and the B on their right. The second example follows the 'rule' perfectly.